# SameSite: lax cookie doesn't work with Safari

Tags: cookies, safari, cookie-httponly

I have a website [www.hello.app](http://www.hello.app) (example url) and a server [www.server.hello.app](http://www.server.hello.app). The server sends http-only cookie for authentification.

I've added the attribute sameSite: "lax" when creating the cookie. sameSite: "none" and sameSite: "lax" don't work with Safari. It doesn't store any cookie, so the user can't perform any request on the server.

```js
return res
      .status(200)
      .cookie("hello", token, {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + msPerDay * 14),
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "lax",
      })
      .json({ user });
```

I've heard it's a bug, but I can't believe such a widely used browser hamper authenticated requests like this!

Is there a way to fix this?